# What's the meaning of "stained with a blue bag" in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a story titled ["Prelude" written by "Katherine Mansfield"](http://nzetc.victoria.ac.nz/tm/scholarly/tei-ManBlis-t1-body1-d1-d2.html), I came across the following  paragraph:

> After tea Kezia wandered back to their own house. Slowly she walked up
>   the back steps, and through the scullery into the kitchen. Nothing was
>   left in it but a lump of gritty yellow soap in one corner of the
>   kitchen window sill and a piece of flannel **stained with a blue bag** in
>   another.

Please somebody shed some light on the meaning of "**a piece of flannel stained with a blue bag**".

Comment: The phrase is not idiomatic. It means literally what it says. I think it's a non-question.

Comment: http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/poetry_literature/5009108-a_piece_of_flannel_stained_with_a_blue_bag.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the time Katherine Mansfield was writing, a *blue bag*, I recall, was put in with clothes while they were being washed to make them come out looking whiter. I imagine that if the bag stayed in contact with any piece of clothing for too long it would leave a stain.

Comment: You just beat me ... [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=vFFHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA154&dq=%22blue+bag%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SGSyUJz2LMTBygHHoYCQAQ&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22blue%20bag%22&f=false) is detailed instruction on the use of a *blue-bag* from *The Teacher's Manual of Object Lessons in Domestic Economy*, Vol. II, 1899.

Comment: @StoneyB. I know because my mother used them!

Comment: It's a Brit thing, I think. In this country housewives put a measured quantity of bluing into the water, rather than dipping a bag, or they purchased detergent with bluing premixed.

Comment: @WillHunting Read the link!

Comment: @WillHunting Speaking from my experience in the cleaning compounds industry, it's like mixing paints. Fabrics yellow over time; add a little blue dye and they look more like new. This also explains the proverbial blue-haired lady. She has had her slightly yellowed "white" hair tinted with blue dye to render it more of a silver white.